# Folding without Monoid instance

Tags: haskell, tree, monoids

I have a simple tree structure:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

And a **Foldable** implementation:

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

instance F.Foldable Tree where
  foldMap f Leaf         = mempty
  foldMap f (Node x l r) = F.foldMap f l `mappend`
                           f x           `mappend`
                           F.foldMap f r
```

And it works even though there's no implementation for `Monoid` and I can't use neither `mappend` nor `mempty` in my code. Then how does this `Foldable` implementation work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you examine the type for `foldMap`

```
class Foldable f where
  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

You'll see that it has an unbound type `m`. Generally when this occurs it means that `m` could be *anything*, but here it also constrains `m` with `Monoid m`. That's there the `Monoid` comes from.

It's worth noting that if we didn't have the `Monoid` instance then it's quite hard to define a function that returns a value that "could be anything". If you try it, you'll find it's almost impossible (without "cheating").

```
impossible :: Int -> b -- no constraints on `b` at all!
impossible i = ...?
```

But it's quite easy if we know a little bit about the type

```
veryPossible  :: Num b => Int -> b
veryPossible  i = fromIntegral i
-- or
veryPossible2 i = fromIntegral (i * i) + fromIntegral i
```

---

As another example, consider the type of the expression

```
expr m = mconcat [m <> m <> mempty, mempty <> m]
```

since this expression is built up based on some unknown value `m` and uses *only* the functions in the `Monoid` class or their derivatives, it's type reflects that. The most general type of `expr` is

```
expr :: Monoid m => m -> m
```

Again here, `m` is a free type variable constrained to be *some* `Monoid`.

---

The reason `foldMap` lets you use `Monoid` functions is because it explicitly constrains the kinds of things that the `m` in its type signature can be. By putting constraints there we gain more power to manipulate them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. `m` is bounded even twice. First here:
`foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m`.


And I used `mappend` defining `foldMap` (thaat's the second bound), it can't come from nowhere, can it?

Comment: Yes, and that bound is why you can use `mappend` and `mempty` in the definition of `foldMap` wherever `m` is expected. You can't use it for the `Tree` itself as that's disjoint from `m` and represented by `f` here.

Comment: It looks like a kind of magic. "It's not a `Monoid`, but it can act like one sometimes".

I'm reading this chapter [link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) and can't find something like what you told me.

Comment: It's definitely strange at first. It might be a good idea to fire up GHCi and define some functions using `let x = ...` and then typecheck them (`:t x`) to see what their "most general type" is. Frequently you'll see the more powerful and varied the things that go into the definition, the more exact their types are. That's the same thing going on here, but in reverse---a more specific type constraint gives you more power to define your instance.

Comment: Go even further.  Look at the type of `foldMap`, as specialized to your `Tree` type.  `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Tree a -> m`. `Tree` and `m` are entirely unrelated types. `m` is declared to be the caller's choice of `Monoid` instance, so your definition of `foldMap` gets to use that.